# Disable any Browser Save & Save as button by css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to disable any Browser Save & Save as option on file menu button by css or javascript? if so then please tell me the way out. thanks

Comment: It's impossible to disable those functions.

Comment: Load your content in a popup. Use images instead of plain text. Disable left and right mouse click. Show the user's IP telling them you're logging it. Do enough so that the user never visits your site ever again. And your data will be safe again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer: Everything you show in your site is downloaded automatically by the browser. 
Even if you find a way to "disable" these functions it would still be possible to find the files in the cache folders of the browser. Best way to protect your content is to watermark it and obfuscate your javascript that's about all you can do.